# how to specify the path of generated debug binary file when debug go-lang in vs-code

Tags: debugging, go, visual-studio-code

## How to specify the path of generated debug binary file when debug go-lang in vs-code?

I have tried modify launch.json file but not work.
I can debug go programs well now in vs-code, the only problem is each time i finish debug, a debug binary file was generated under my project directory, like the picture below.

I want to know can i specify the directory of generated debug binary file?

I am on mac screen shot of my problem:
[image]

Comment: A fix should soon be released. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is followed by [vscode-go issue 1345](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1345): "Delete binary files created by delve after closing the debug session"

> `delve` is the debugger for Golang, or at least it's the one that the Go extension uses.
>   When you debug something with delve, it creates a large binary file in the current directory. If you debug a main function (`dlv debug`), you get '`debug`'. If you debug a test function (`dlv test`), you get '`debug.test`'.
>
> In normal delve usage, when you're done, you quit delve. Delve then deletes this file. Apparently VSCode gracelessly terminates (SIGKILL?) delve, which means the file sticks around.

So this is  studied, <del>but not yet resolved</del>.

---

Update July 2018: **[Ramya Rao](https://github.com/ramya-rao-a)** adds in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1345#issuecomment-406125202):

> I finally have an update!
>
> Turns out **there is a command called `Detach` that can be called on the `delve` server which will result in the required clean up of the debug binary that gets generated**.
>   To get this fix before the next update to the Go extension (which will be either Friday or early next week), please follow the below:
>
> - Download https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/blob/master/Go-latest.vsix
> - Run `code --install-extension Go-latest.vsix`
>     If the above fails with `Error: end of central directory record signature not found`, then clone [this repo (vsgo)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/) and use the `Go-latest.vsix` file from the cloned repo
> - Reload VS Code
>
> The fix worked for me as long as the program being debugged wasn't spawning processes of its own like a web server for which I have logged an upstream issue with delve.
>
> I'd appreciate it if folks here can give the fix a try and share any feedback.
>
> The change you need to do to provide an output path for the generated debug binary is in the `launch.json` file.
>   Use the property output in your debug configuration.
>   Please don't modify the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

This debug file was generated by delve when debugging and should be deleted after debugging, this seems to be bug of go extension of vs-code, see the link [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1345)